How to add inline image in Azure Devops work item description or comment using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient?
It is easy to add an inline image to the work item's description or comment using web interface, but I did not found how to do that using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient from the code in samples: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs
How can it be done in Azure DevOps?

Using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient to add an inline image to the work item's description or comment is not directly support.
But we can upload the attachment first, and then add the image inline by referencing the attachment path.
Here is the sample code to upload an image to attachment, then add a comment and update the description with the attachment Url.
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Full path to the image file to upload as an attachment
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\img.png";

            Uri orgUrl = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/orgname");
            var projectName = "projectname";
            var workItemId = 21; // replace with your work item ID
            string pat = "";

            // Create a connection
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(orgUrl, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, pat));
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            // Create the Attachment
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting upload of: {0}", filePath);
            AttachmentReference attachment = workItemTrackingClient.CreateAttachmentAsync(@filePath).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(" Attachment created, URL  : {0}", attachment.Url);

            // Create the comment with the Attachment Url
            var comment = new CommentCreate
            {
                Text = "<div>This is  an inline image &nbsp;<img src=\"" + attachment.Url+"\" alt=\"imagename.png\"></div>"
            };

            // Call the method to add the comment
            var task = workItemTrackingClient.AddCommentAsync(comment, projectName, workItemId);
            task.Wait();
            var result = task.Result;

            // Print the comment ID
            Console.WriteLine($"Comment added with ID: {result.Id}");


            // Create a JsonPatchDocument
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();
            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/System.Description",
                    Value = "<div>This is  an inline image &nbsp;<img src=\"" + attachment.Url + "\" alt=\"imagename.png\"></div>"
                }
            );

            // Call the method to update the Description
            var task1 = workItemTrackingClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument,workItemId);
            task1.Wait();
            var updatedWorkItem = task1.Result;

            Console.WriteLine($"Updated Description of work item {updatedWorkItem.Id} successfully.");
        }
    }
}

Test result:

